# The result of the logic diagram

Tags: logic, diagram

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3e8.png]

If i'm understanding correctly, the first set of this diagram is **AC**, then second set is just **D**, and the last set is **B**.

So is it correct to write: F = AC + D + B?

Answer (score 0):

The first set is: 
    `((A) and (C))`

The second set is:
    `((not B) and (D))`

The third set is:
    `((B) and (not D))`

All 3 sets are in an OR with each other, and the result of that OR is
    `(F)`